# What is the purpose of "Change Tracking" in SCD Type-2 Loader in SAS?

Tags: sas, scd

What is the purpose of "Change Tracking" in SCD Type-2 Loader in SAS ?
What is Start date and end date time ?

Comment: think of it like 'source control' for data - it lets you store the history of changes to the data over time, a "version" history if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Try the documentation, "SAS(R) Data Integration Studio 4.9: User's Guide" section "[Working with Slowly Changing Dimensions][1]" should get you started. The section topics are:

> About Slowly Changing Dimensions
>   About Dimension Tables
>   About Fact Tables
>   Usage Notes for Slowly Changing Dimensions
>   Loading a Dimension Table with Type 1 Updates
>   Loading a Dimension Table with Type 1 and 2 Updates
>   Comparing Tables
>   Loading a Fact Table Using Dimension Table Lookup
>   Loading a Table and Adding a Surrogate Primary Key
>   Tracking Changes in Source Datetime Values
>   Closing Out Rows in Datetime Change Tracking